# How to compare array keys and find key values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
array[Key1][A]{values....}
array[key2][B]{values....}
```

But Some times the array will like

```
array[Key1][A]{values....}
array[Key1][B]{values....}
array[key2][C]{values....}
```

How can I know index Key1 contains two keys and get value of the key.....I need to compare the key values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Array constructed dynamically .... so the key may be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract array keys with `array_keys` Then iterate array. Below some variation about this

```
//your input array
$array = array();
//This callback function must return some value which will be putt to result array
$func = function ($k) {
   //Check if there is more than one element in this cell
   if (count($array[$k]) > 1) {
      //now you can do sth with that array ie. extract additional keys with array_keys($array[$k]) and return some value
      return ;
   }
   //return some value to result array
   return ;
}
$retArr = array_map($func, array_keys($array));
```